# EJS render no output

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, viewengine

I am trying to use EJS but whenever res.render is called, it just hangs there with no response.

This is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var router = require('./router/index')(app);
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// Internal Server error
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(8888);
```

And in my routes file

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use('/', require('./routes/Website'));
  app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/UsersRoute'));
  app.use('/api/keys', require('./routes/KeysRoute'));
};
```

And in the website file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Get all Users data
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'The index page!' })
});
```

I have a `index.eps` file in `views` folder and a `layout.eps` in the layout folder. What am i doing wrong in this?

Comment: make it index.ejs .EJS use .ejs  extension to save file.

Comment: My files are saved in .ejs and I've tried using `res.render('index.ejs', { title: 'The index page!' })` However the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Should your internal server error middleware have a conditional?? It seems to me that it would try to send the response from your middleware every time a route is called.

Try commenting out the `res` in your middleware and try calling `next();`

Comment: Thanks this solved the hanging issue but I'm getting `Cannot GET /` message now. My els file is in views folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by removing

```
// Internal Server error
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
});
```

And seems like EJS looks for views folder in the root directory instead of the directory of the .js file